# SQL Avg for column ordered by another column

Tags: sql

I have data that looks like this

```
Country GDP  Unemployment 
USA     2.13 13.83
Canada  1.83 17.28
Mexico  1.28 26.28
...     ...  ...
...     ...  ...
...     ...  ...
```

I want to write a query that will give me the average unemployment for the top ten countries by GDP.
So my desired output is just

```
AVG(unemployment)
#
```

I am having a hard time getting the average unemployment for only the top ten countries by GDP. I am getting the average for ALL countries, but I only want it for the top ten.

So do I order by GDP? Been trying something like this, but not working.

```
select AVG(unemployment)
from data
order by GDP limit 10 desc;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subquery.  Using the syntax your question suggests:

```
select AVG(unemployment)
from (select d.*
      from data d
      order by GDP desc
      limit 10
     ) d
```